# Building and installing "odvr" for Olympus voice recorders

Tags: sound

I tried to to build odvr (https://github.com/twilly/odvr) but I get this after typing `sudo make odvr`:

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags`   -c -o olympusdvr.o olympusdvr.c
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
olympusdvr.c:24:21: fatal error: sndfile.h: File o directory non esistente
 #include <sndfile.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
<incorporato>: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "olympusdvr.o" non riuscito
make: *** [olympusdvr.o] Errore 1
```

What should I do? I need it for my university (then I use Audacity or others to convert to MP3…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a couple of supporting libraries `libsndfile` `libusb` as the [github page](https://github.com/twilly/odvr) says

> Libusb and libsndfile, and their associated development headers, are
>   required

Try

```
 sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev libusb-dev
```

Comment: I installed the libraries, but it gives me errors about the icons (but I thought it was irrelevant since it has no GUI), so I built and installed it and when I execute `sudo odvr -l` it says "command not found" :-\

Comment: well you will need to execute it as `sudo ./odvr` if it is not installed into a $PATH location and your in the same directory as the built executable. Else you might want to try `sudo make install` and this will put it in a place that will be in $PATH

Comment: Here's the output: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1t8E3l2sNGzbc41-qxqKE29ePclD4Npv6SYCLdsWFvGU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JKandy-drew `sudo ./odvr` will work if you are in the directory which contains `odvr`. You might have to run `cd /path/to/the/right/directory/` first.

Comment: @pomsky, I know, I open the terminal in the window of the extracted files of the zip.

Actually I don't know a way to install it, so this the only way to make it to work. :-\

Comment: @JKandy-drew Okay, but you didn't include the "*...open the terminal in the window of the extracted files...*" part in your proposed edit. So it would have been a potentially harmful and futile suggestions for new users especially. That's why your edit suggestion was rejected.